# my basic w3.includeHTML() includes nothing in a basic test executed on my PC server

Tags: javascript, html, include, w3.js

In debug, the include created about 30 temporary file named VMnnnn where n is an integer.  Each file contains the single letter "z". None of the text to be included is there.

I created an html include file that has only text within paragraphs, i.e.

some text

I invoke  area without error.
I traced the w3 invocations.

I am using Visual Studio Code, MAMP server, and executing debug as Launch Chrome.  I tried Live Server, but read the w3.js should be tested when running in a server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>  
  <script src="../js/testHtmlInclude.js"></script>
</head>
  <body class="container">
    <img 
      src = "../notables/notable1.jpg" 
      style = "width:200px; height:300px;"
      >
    <h1>Nipper, K9</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Illo similique quisquam nostrum, omnis itaque aspernatur explicabo
    dolor minima officiis sequi.</p>  
    <div w3-include-html="../notables/notable1.html"></div> 
    </body>  
  </html>

testHtmlInclude.js: w3.includeHTML();

notable1.html: 


<p><b>Lorem ipsum</b> Dolor sit Amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum
recusandae unde a quas omnis ex vitae nobis quae, laudantium saepe! 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate 
explicabo minima libero, omnis fugit exercitationem quae sit asperiores 
veniam iure quisquam delectus velit odit unde laudantium assumenda!
</p>
```

I expect the html code in the include file to be included.  Nothing was.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I have to invoke the w3.includeHTML() function at the point in the code where I want the copied HTML placed.  I had defined the function in the  but didn't invoke it (very embarrassing).  This is what i should have done:

```
<body>
<div w3.include.html="path & filename"></div>
<script> w3includeHTML();</script>
</body>
```

I hope this helps other neophytes!